# How can I set user/group ownership on a SaltStack git clone?

Tags: saltstack

I have a hand-maintained Bugzilla installation that I'm trying to move to being managed with SaltStack. Currently I have the following `.sls` file to set up the clone:

```
https://github.com/bugzilla/bugzilla.git:
  git.latest:
    - rev: release-5.0-stable
    - branch: release-5.0-stable
    - target: /srv/http/bugzilla
    - require:
      - pkg: git
```

My current install has the permissions locked down to basically `root:www-data`, with owner read-write and group read-only. (IIRC, the Bugzilla install guide said to do this.) I'd like to replicate this configuration with the Salt clone, but can't seem to figure it out. `salt.states.git` has an option for the user to run the clone as, but nothing about the group (and besides, you can't fiddle with file modes either). It seems like the Right Way™ to do this is to use a `salt.states.file` state, which `require`s the `git.latest` state, but all the `file` states in the documentation copy stuff from the master, which is not what I want.

How can I set the owner/group/permissions on my new clone?

Comment: How about creating a state with file.directory specifying name, group, dir_mode, file_mode with recurse: for user, group and mode.